# Unable to update gcloud cli on WSL debian

Tags: debian, gcloud, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Running on Windows 10, WSL Debian

I'm attempting to upgrade from version 376.0.0 of gcloud to a slightly more recent version. I also get a similar error when upgrading to the latest version as well but thought that maybe if the upgrade jump was less I wouldn't have issues.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-cli=381.0.0-0
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Hit:3 http://ftp.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
Hit:5 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:6 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-bullseye InRelease
Hit:7 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease
Hit:8 https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/10/prod buster InRelease
Hit:9 https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com bullseye InRelease
Get:10 https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease [3,917 B]
Err:10 https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 23F3D4EA75716059
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 23F3D4EA75716059
W: Failed to fetch https://cli.github.com/packages/dists/stable/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 23F3D4EA75716059
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  google-cloud-cli-app-engine-java google-cloud-cli-app-engine-python google-cloud-cli-pubsub-emulator google-cloud-cli-bigtable-emulator
  google-cloud-cli-datastore-emulator kubectl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  google-cloud-cli
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 105 not upgraded.
Need to get 130 MB of archives.
After this operation, 705 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-bullseye/main amd64 google-cloud-cli all 381.0.0-0 [130 MB]
Ign:1 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-bullseye/main amd64 google-cloud-cli all 381.0.0-0
Get:1 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-bullseye/main amd64 google-cloud-cli all 381.0.0-0 [130 MB]
Fetched 130 MB in 50s (2,584 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 133563 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../google-cloud-cli_381.0.0-0_all.deb ...
Unpacking google-cloud-cli (381.0.0-0) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/google-cloud-cli_381.0.0-0_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/google-cloud-sdk/VERSION', which is also in package google-cloud-sdk 376.0.0-0
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/google-cloud-cli_381.0.0-0_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: I ended up solving this using the method proposed in: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062171/dpkg-deb-error-paste-subprocess-was-killed-by-signal-broken-pipe

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to missing public key:

```
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 23F3D4EA75716059
```

From the [gcloud installation document](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#deb):

> Import the Google Cloud public key. If your distribution's apt-key
> command supports the --keyring argument, run the following command:

```
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -
```

> If your distribution's apt-key command doesn't support the --keyring
> argument, run the following command:

```
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

> If you can't get latest updates due to an expired key, [obtain the
> latest apt-get.gpg key file.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/known-issues#known_issues_for_linux_vm_instances)

Comment: Yeah, this is the documentation. I don't  know about the OP, but I am here because it did not solve the issue.